# Larave Pagination is showing localhost not my domain

Tags: laravel, pagination

I am using a laravel application where all my pagination URLs are wrong. They are not using my domain like https://example.com instead it is showing `localhost:3000` on the live server.

All other URLs and routes are working fine but pagination has issues. Please guide, I have used

```
{-- $order->link() --}
{{ $orders->render() }}
```

also, I have tried

```
{!! str_replace(request()->server('SERVER_ADDR'), "example.com",  $orders->links()) !!}
```

But it always shows `localhost:3000`

Comment: Have you updated the `APP_URL` on env on your live

Comment: Yes APP_URL is pointing to domain name

Comment: could you show the controller code as well?

Comment: UserOrder::join('shipping_address','users_orders.id','=','shipping_address.order_id')
                ->whereHas('products', function ($product) {
                    return $product->where('name', '!=', 'LIT für Filling')
                        ->where('name', '!=', 'LIT für Refund');
                })
                ->where( 'users_orders.delivery_name', 'Packstation' )
                ->where( 'shipping_address.recipient_first_name', null )
                ->orderByDesc( 'users_orders.id' )
                ->paginate( 10, [ '*' ], 'page_packing_station', $pageNumber );

Comment: have you tried `php artisan config:clear` ?

Comment: Yes I have done config:clear   cache:clear and view:clear  but nothing is working

Comment: make it as paginate();